# Git in Visual Studio : Where is checkout?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

All

I already seen same topic, but it have no replies.

I have Visual Studio 2015 and latest Git for windows. I work with Git in Bash as well, but it does not comfortable for me. Together with that, Visual Studio does not contain only two popular commands: checkout and remove specific commit.

Why the world of version control so cruel for novice developers...

Just look at this:[print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSz1j.png)
. It has everything you need, but of course, except checkout and remove.

Please help, how I can resolve the problem? 
Maybe exist any extension for VS2015 or maybe I can add the points to this menu via coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember well (because I don't use it due to its bad ergonomic and lack of some essential features), you can't checkout a specific revision/commit, just existing branches. 
Otherwise, you will end up in a 'detached head' state, which is something that could be confusing, add complexity when you learn git and that Microsoft should make some efforts to handle gracefully and explain to the user.

Perhaps in a next version...

Ps: Sometimes, the lack of support of some features is due to the library that git support of visual studio is based on, that doesn't support 100% of the git features yet. They should implement the feature in this library first (libgit2 /libgit2sharp).
Boring lack of rebase in the past was due to that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it seems the way it is. I hope in the next version, they will add at least functional from Code.

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to use the Command Palette. The Visual Studio team posted a good explanation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/versioncontrol). I'll include the relevant parts:

> You can create and checkout branches directly within VS code through the Command Palette. Press <kbd>Ctrl + P</kbd>, type `git` and then press <kbd>Space</kbd>. You should see the following:

[image: command palette]

> If you type `checkout` and press <kbd>Space</kbd> again, you will see a dropdown containing all of the branches or tags in the current repository.

[image: checkout]

> The `git branch` command lets you quickly create a new branch. Just provide the name of your new branch and VS Code will create the branch and switch to it.

Comment: You are confusing 'Visual studio', the IDE with a not so good support of git with 'Visual Studio code', the advanced and multi-platform text editor with a quite good and different git support.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @Philippe Thanks, sorry about that. Microsoft product names can be confusing.